# Convert Number to Word android

Tags: java, android

```
 static public class ScaleUnit{
        private int exponent;
        private String[] names;
        private ScaleUnit(int exponent, String...names){
            this.exponent = exponent;
            this.names = names;
        }
        public int getExponent(){
            return exponent;
        }
        public String getName(int index){
            return names[index];
        }
    }
static private ScaleUnit[] Scale_UNITS = new ScaleUnit[]{
            new ScaleUnit(6, "Million"),
            new ScaleUnit(9, "Billion"),
            new ScaleUnit(12, "Trillion"),
            new ScaleUnit(15, "Quadrillion"),
            new ScaleUnit(18, "Quintillion"),
            new ScaleUnit(21, "Sextillion"),
            new ScaleUnit(24, "Septillion"),
            new ScaleUnit(27, "Octillion"),
            new ScaleUnit(30, "Nonillion"),
            new ScaleUnit(33, "Decillion"),
            new ScaleUnit(36, "Undecillion"),
            new ScaleUnit(39, "Duodecillion"),
            new ScaleUnit(42, "Tredecillion"),
            new ScaleUnit(45, "Quattuordecillion"),
            new ScaleUnit(48, "Quinquadecillion"),
            new ScaleUnit(51, "Sedecillion"),
            new ScaleUnit(54, "Septendecillion"),
            new ScaleUnit(57, "Octodecillion"),
            new ScaleUnit(60, "Novendecillion"),
            new ScaleUnit(63, "Vigintillion"),
            new ScaleUnit(66, "Unvigintillion"),
            new ScaleUnit(69, "Duovigintillion"),
            new ScaleUnit(72, "Tresvigintillion"),
            new ScaleUnit(75, "Quattuorvigintillion"),
            new ScaleUnit(78, "Quinquavigintillion"),
            new ScaleUnit(81, "Sesvigintillion"),
            new ScaleUnit(84, "Septemvigintillion"),
            new ScaleUnit(87, "Octovigintillion"),
            new ScaleUnit(90, "Novemvigintillion"),
            new ScaleUnit(93, "Trigintillion"),
            new ScaleUnit(96, "Untrigintillion"),
            new ScaleUnit(99, "Duotrigintillion"),
            new ScaleUnit(102, "Trestrigintillion"),
            new ScaleUnit(105, "Quattuortrigintillion"),
            new ScaleUnit(108, "Quinquatrigintillion"),
            new ScaleUnit(111, "Sestrigintillion"),
            new ScaleUnit(114, "Septentrigintillion"),
            new ScaleUnit(117, "Octotrigintillion"),
            new ScaleUnit(120, "Noventrigintillion"),
            new ScaleUnit(123, "Quadragintillion"),
            new ScaleUnit(153, "Quinquagintillion"),
            new ScaleUnit(183, "Sexagintillion"),
            new ScaleUnit(213, "Septuagintillion"),
            new ScaleUnit(243, "Octogintillion"),
            new ScaleUnit(273, "Nonagintillion"),
            new ScaleUnit(303, "Centillion"),
            new ScaleUnit(306, "Uncentillion"),
            new ScaleUnit(309, "Duocentillion"),
            new ScaleUnit(312, "Trescentillion"),
            new ScaleUnit(333, "Decicentillion"),
            new ScaleUnit(336, "Undecicentillion"),
            new ScaleUnit(363, "Viginticentillion"),
            new ScaleUnit(366, "Unviginticentillion"),
            new ScaleUnit(393, "Trigintacentillion"),
            new ScaleUnit(423, "Quadragintacentillion"),
            new ScaleUnit(453, "Quinquagintacentillion"),
            new ScaleUnit(483, "Sexagintacentillion"),
            new ScaleUnit(513, "Septuagintacentillion"),
            new ScaleUnit(543, "Octogintacentillion"),
            new ScaleUnit(573, "Nonagintacentillion"),
            new ScaleUnit(603, "Ducentillion"),
            new ScaleUnit(903, "Trecentillion"),
            new ScaleUnit(1203, "Quadringentillion"),
            new ScaleUnit(1503, "Quingentillion"),
            new ScaleUnit(1803, "Sescentillion"),
            new ScaleUnit(2103, "Septingentillion"),
            new ScaleUnit(2403, "Octingentillion"),
            new ScaleUnit(2703, "Nongentillion"),
            new ScaleUnit(3003, "Millinillion"),

    };
static public enum Scale {
        SHORT;

        public String getName(int exponent){
            for (ScaleUnit unit: Scale_UNITS){
                if (unit.getExponent() == exponent){
                    return unit.getName(this.ordinal());
                }
            }
            return "";
        }
    }
```

I have this list and codes. And I want to strip the number and convert words. like 160392 = 1Million or 79938384472 = 79Billion.
what I figure if I have right number match with exponent it does pull out words but if not match with exponent, it returns null.

Answer (score 0):

Divide by 3 and multiply by 3 to get to the nearest "valid" exponent value, like so :

```
    public String getName(int exponent){
        exponent = (exponent / 3) * 3;
        for (ScaleUnit unit: Scale_UNITS){
            if (unit.getExponent() == exponent){
                return unit.getName(this.ordinal());
            }
        }
        return "";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

A suggestion: Make sure the scale units array is sorted by exponent (I believe it is in your code). Convert the number to a string, e.g., `"79938384472"`. Find the scale unit that has the greatest exponent strictly less than the lentgh of the string. In the example, the length is 11, so you need `ScaleUnit(9, "Billion")`. Taking the exponent from that scale unit, strip off this many chars from the end of the string (`79938384472` becomes `79`). Concatenate the truncated string with the name from the scale unit.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want to head for a slightly different, IMO yet clearer approach:

Map ranges of exponents to words.

For example, you would map [6-8] to "Million", [9-11] to "Billion" etc.
To accomplish this, you can make use of [Guavas `RangeMap`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/16.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/RangeMap.html):

```
RangeMap<Integer, String> expWordRanges =
     ImmutableRangeMap.builder()
                      .put(Range.closedOpen(6,9), "Million")
                      .put(Range.closedOpen(9,12), "Billion")
                      // etc.
                      .build();
String word = expWordRanges.get(exponent);
```

---

However, although separation of concerns is usually a good thing, the design here discloses that you would have to decompose the actual number twice:

1. to pass the exponent to the word determining method
2. implicitly to get the remainder - which is dependent on the result of the word method

Example:

Given 21 277 185
Should result in 21 Million.

You would now

1. get the number of places (your 'exponent') = 8
2. pass it to the word method = Million
3. calculate the prefix, e.g by dividing through thousand until less than thousand (exponent divided through 3 iterations/floored, rounded downwards - the second touch with the exponent). Cf. to @Ole V.V.'s answer

   > Find the scale unit that has the greatest exponent strictly less than the length of the string

Step 3 is independent can be done as first step. If you now count the number of iterations and multiply it with 3, you get exactly the number you need to pass to your original `getName` method. Furthermore you don't need to break up the number twice now.

Given that Integer is somewhat limited in Java, I guess that you already deal with Strings here, as @Ole V.V. also suggests. Therefore, the decomposition obviously deals with the String's length rather than powers of 10, thousand respectively. That takes me back to the solution I mentioned in the beginning of my post.